# Is there any ActionScript 3 to JavaScript (and vice versa) migration guide?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, migration

as a skilled AS3 developer I wonder if there is something like **AS3** to **JS** migration guide. After all both languages have a lot in common.

I have in mind something like the old [AS2 to AS3 migration guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/index.html?migration.html&all-classes.html) - a list where I could simply look up the AS3 functionality and the JS counterpart, or vice versa.

I am not saying you can easily convert all your code like that but it would tell me where to start.

---

PS: I think it is a great idea and if such guide doesn't exist someone should write one :).

Comment: imho `js = as2 - graphic classes + regexp`. so it's easy to translate **js <=> as2** and then **AS2 <=> AS3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have a difficult time of this considering a lot of the flash.* packages don't have any native JavaScript counterparts. Maybe a robust JavaScript library can ease the transition, but there will be a lot not migrate-able.

However, many of the Top-level datatypes do have a JavaScript counterpart (i.e; Date, Array, String, Object, null, Number/Integer)

Comment: In my opinion that makes such guide even more compelling.

Answer (score 2):

I've read that with [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) you can compile somewhat transparently to JS code. This requires Haxe code, I think, which is not ActionScript 3.0 but is close and should be easy to pick up if you're already comfortable with AS.

I haven't tried this myself but it's probably worth to check out. Here's a blog post that might give you some ideas: http://gamehaxe.com/2010/05/25/javascript-ready-or-not/